# Highcharts stacked data, stock like chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts.

I want to have like 30-40 bars but only 7 categories.

```
categories: ['Jan 10', 'Jan 17', 'Fev 3', 'Fev 27', 'Mar 6', 'Mar 16', 'Mar 27']
```

But my data looks like:

```
series: [{
            data: [5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4]
        }, {
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4]
        }]
```

Its possible in highcharts to have just 7 categories but the data length to be greater than categories length?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/yh6mgq3y/

I want to remove the numbers from 7 ... 27 on categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have columns grouped together, example:

[Stacked and grouped columns](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped)

So this enables to have multiple columns and fewer categories.